# Hang in mixed mode MFC app

Tags: mfc, windbg

I have A 32 bit MFC app with some .NET 2.0  assemblies loaded.
Have received a dump because it appears to hang (is frozen ). Running on w7-64

For me it looks like the FinalizerThread is to blame, but how can I find the root cause ?

```
Loaded symbol image file: mscorwks.dll
Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll


 0:006> !analyze -hang -v
<Cut some verbose output>
BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: 77c

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   6   d48.3fc Pseudo Thread Handle   

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~6s;k;;

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

BlockedOn_EventHandle
Tid    [0x3fc]


BLOCKING_THREAD:  000003fc
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BlockedOn_EventHandle
THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  3088ee7b2b2c579d04c782e4cf604f0179eeb747
THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  75f294bbc1ac358b92e8d5e7660d0d49028dba99
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 76bc15e9 to 774a015d
FAULTING_THREAD:  000003fc

STACK_TEXT:  
0751fc5c 76bc15e9 00000002 0751fcac 00000001     ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15
0751fcf8 750519fc 0751fcac 0751fd20 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x100
0751fd40 750541d8 00000002 7efde000 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xe0
0751fd5c 72caef76 00000002 7317a410 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
0751fd7c 72cb2f46 002e4498 0751fe80 002e44c8 mscorwks!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x77
0751fd90 72c3a0bf 0751fe80 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x49
0751fda4 72c3a05b 0751fe80 0751fe2c 72d55c37 mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
0751fe38 72c39f81 0751fe80 6bdfde61 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
0751fe74 72ce36ac 0751fe80 00000000 003037c0 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
0751fe9c 72ce36bd 72cb2efb 00000008 0751fee4 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32
0751feac 72d304c4 72cb2efb 6bdfdef1 00000000 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd
0751fee4 72d70647 00000000 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb
0751ff88 7505336a 002e44c8 0751ffd4 774b9f72 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
0751ff94 774b9f72 002e44c8 984bccd8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe



0:006> !threads
ThreadCount: 2
UnstartedThread: 0
BackgroundThread: 2
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 0
Hosted Runtime: no
                                  PreEmptive   GC Alloc           Lock
   ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State     GC       Context       Domain   Count APT         Exception
   0    1  77c 003078f0      4220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003037c0     0 STA
   6    2  3fc 00313de0      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003037c0     0 MTA (Finalizer)


0:006> !pe
There is no current managed exception on this thread
0:000> !FinalizeQueue
SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
STA Interfaces to be released: 0
----------------------------------
generation 0 has 1 finalizable objects (00313518->0031351c)
generation 1 has 0 finalizable objects (00313518->00313518)
generation 2 has 0 finalizable objects (00313518->00313518)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (0031351c->0031351c)
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
722e131c        1           56 System.Threading.Thread
Total 1 objects


0:006> ~0s
eax=00000000 ebx=00288a70 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00288a70 edi=00288a70
eip=756a78d7 esp=0018fe88 ebp=0018fea8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
user32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15:
756a78d7 83c404          add     esp,4
0:000> kn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0018fe88 756a7c1d user32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15
01 0018fea8 7417a685 user32!GetMessageA+0xa1
02 0018fec4 7417ad32 mfc90!AfxInternalPumpMessage+0x1a [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153]
03 0018fee4 7414717d mfc90!CWinThread::Run+0x5b [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 629]
04 0018fef8 00412b18 mfc90!AfxWinMain+0x6a [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\winmain.cpp @ 47]
05 0018ff88 7505336a <MyMFCApp>+0x12b18
06 0018ff94 774b9f72 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
07 0018ffd4 774b9f45 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
08 0018ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Update:

```
0:000> !eeheap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x05381018
generation 1 starts at 0x0538100c
generation 2 starts at 0x05381000
ephemeral segment allocation context: (0x0539044c, 0x05391ff4)
 segment    begin allocated     size
05380000 05381000  05391ff4 0x00010ff4(69620)
Large object heap starts at 0x06381000
 segment    begin allocated     size
06380000 06381000  0638d488 0x0000c488(50312)
Total Size   0x1d47c(119932)
------------------------------
GC Heap Size   0x1d47c(119932)
```

Update 2:

I have ran  !DumpHeap 0x05381018   (from generation 0 starts at),
no error output. Also ran  !VerifyHeap  and !heap -s –v (on the native heaps) with no suspicious output.

Comment: @Thomas Weller  , my sos 2.0.50727.5485, does not support  !dumpheap -gen 0   is !eeheap -gc  the same ?

Comment: To me it doesn't look like a 'freeze'. Main thread appears to be happily pumping messages. Finalizer thread seems to be waiting for an event. To me it looks fully operational - you might be chasing ghost here...

Comment: @Skomialek  yes maybe, but the user of the app claimed that it was not possible to operate anymore. However I have seen disconnected mouse and or keyboards when some user claims hung app.